# Test Result Analyzer plugin not catching results

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I want to use this plugin with Jenkins.
My project is in Maven(Java) with IntelliJ.
How to give path to test analyzer to produce reports by using TestNG result's report???
Please explain with all the steps

Answer (score 0):

I was making mistake to give path for 
/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml   This is correct

\target\surefire-reports\testng-results.xml   This is wrong